# How do I allow newlines in an XSD restriction?

Tags: python, xml, xsd

I'm parsing some XML files where some elements have inner CDATA text (and must contain a non-null amount of non-whitespace) that contains newlines that are important to retain. I was attempting to write an XSD to validate this, but my initial attempt of `.*` as the restriction failed because, at least in the Python xmlschema library I was using, a "." does not match newlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The solution was to use "\S", which matches up against any non-whitespace and "\s", which matches up against any whitespace](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html). The following indicates that this "script" element type must have at least one non-whitespace character in it that may be bracketed by any number of whitespace or non-whitespace characters:

```
<xs:simpleType name="script">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
    <xs:pattern value="[\s\S]*\S[\s\S]*"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```